# List.Find using a struct list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with this specific topic.
I have a list of struct element which I need to use as argument in a method.

```
public struct MyStruct
{

    public string F1;
    public string F2;

}

List<MyStruct> NewList = new List<MyStruct>();
NewList.Add(new MyStruct { F1 = "AAA", F2 = "BBB" });
NewList.Add(new MyStruct { F1 = "CCC", F2 = "DDD" });
```

If I try to find on item of that list using LINQ I can use:
    var Element = NewList.Find(x => x.F1 == "AAA");

but Element returns something I cannot convert to a list?
I can use Element.F1 or Element.F2 but if I need to pass the Element itself to a method how should I do it? 
Also, if I try to define Element as:

```
List<MyStruct> Element = NewList.Find(x => x.F1 == "AAA");
```

It fails! But why?
Isn't Element of that structure?
.Find searches for an element which are 2 strings defined in the struct fields F1 and F2.

If I use .FindAll the error seems to go away on the definition `List<MyStruct> Element`?
How can I define one single Element for NewList?

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "It fails! But why? Isn't Element of that structure?" Tip: Hover over `Find` to see what it returns. It doesn't return a List, it returns a single MyStruct object. Find isn't a filter operation.

Comment: if you want to find all matching elements you should use `Where`

Comment: If the .Find returns one element I need to collect the result in a `MyStruct` element (not in a list), right? At least if I'm sure there is only one.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.Find` returns with a single element and not with a `List<T>`. You should declare your `Element` variable as `MyStruct`:

```
MyStruct Element = NewList.Find(x => x.F1 == "AAA");
```

You should also think about that `Find` returns the default value of the type you store in your list when it couldn't find a matching value.

Comment: Hi John, understood (very basic now that you realize it). Thanks.